# How to assign Hex value to Heap Memory in C

Tags: c, memory-management, hex

I am trying to create a memory allocator in C (basically recreate malloc() using mmap()), but part of the specification is that if a debug flag is on, I need to initially fill my allocated memory with the recognizable Hex pattern 0xDEADBEEF, as necessary. I have been able to create the code responsible for initializing the memory block, but I don't know how to methodically assign hex values to memory. My code is below:

```
static void *base;          
struct free_header *head;       
int successfulInit = 0;
int GlobalDebug = 0;

struct free_header {

  int size;         
  struct free_header *next; 

};


struct object_header {

  int size;         
  int test;     

};

int m_error;

int Mem_Init(int sizeOfRegion, int debug) {

  if (sizeOfRegion <= 0) {
    m_error = E_BAD_ARGS;
    return -1;
  } else if (successfulInit == 1) {
    m_error = E_BAD_ARGS;
    return -1;
  }
  GlobalDebug = debug;
  // open the /dev/zero device
  int fd = open("/dev/zero", O_RDWR);

  // need to see if its divisible and returns a whole number
  int pageSize = getpagesize();
  int newSize = sizeOfRegion;
  if((sizeOfRegion%pageSize) != 0){
    int addTo = pageSize - (sizeOfRegion % pageSize);
    newSize += addTo;
  }

  // size (in bytes) needs to be evenly divisble by the page size
  base = mmap(NULL, newSize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
  if (base == MAP_FAILED || base == NULL) {
    m_error = E_BAD_ARGS;
    return -1;  
  }

  head = base;
  head->size = newSize;
  head->next = NULL;

  // close the device
  close(fd);

  // set flag saying the call was successful
  successfulInit = 1;
  return 0;
}
```

Any help or suggestions are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you make sure the address returned from mmap() is properly aligned, then you can cast the void pointer, which the mmap() returned to any other pointer like int and then use a simple loop to set you values. I quote from specs: *A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type.* Just be careful with that, it must be converted to a compatible type.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use `memmove()`:

```
if (debug)
{
    int filler = 0xDEADBEEF;

    void *ptr;
    for (ptr = startByte; ptr - startByte < size; ptr += sizeof(int *))
        memmove(ptr, &filler, sizeof(int *));
}
```

If the size isn't an exact multiple of sizeof(int *), you'll have to copy just part of the filler in the remaining bytes at the end of the region, but that's a start.

Comment: Also known as `memcpy()`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks @itsme86. Can you tell I'm inexperienced?

Comment: -1, This is wrong, int isn't guaranteed to be the same size as a int pointer. If int pointer is size 8 and int is size 4 you are accessing illegal memory.

Comment: @self. Wouldn't that result in a segfault? I just checked and int is size 4, int pointer is size 8, so you are correct.

Comment: @ngwilliams It will cause undefined behaviour, and from that anything can happen( read as: probably). You shouldn't use that code even if they were equal.

Comment: Alright @self., thanks for your help. I'll leave it open for more answers.